# how to apply single click on 3 items of listview or how to club 3 items for single click in android

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

i have `listview` with 4 items on it ,i need one click event on 3 items of `listview`.
so how to club three item to apply click event on it .
.

state ,view and comp these three items are on `listview`

```
    holderView.state.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    holderView.view.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    holderView.comp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    }});
```

thanks

Comment: Implement onItemCLickListner in your activity

Comment: why do you want combine items into one?

Comment: i want to apply click event on 3 items of listview for that i want to club that three item and perform one click event on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways.

**1.** Implement Onclick listener and set Listener to all.

```
 holderView.state.setOnClickListener(this);
 holderView.view.setOnClickListener(this);
 holderView.comp.setOnClickListener(this);

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.id1
            || v.getId() == R.id.id2
            || v.getId() == R.id.id3) {
        // Do your task here
    }
}
```

**2.** Create a single instance of OnCLickListener and set to all.

```
     View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do your stuff      
    }
 };
```

Set it to all your views.

```
holderView.state.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
holderView.view.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
holderView.comp.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```